# Spring dependency Autowiring

Tags: spring-boot, dependency-injection, autowired, spring-ioc

I have a Facade for the persistence submodule exposed through the @Service annotation:

```
@EnableMongoRepositories
@Service
public class MongoFacade {

    @Autowired
    private ShopsRepository shopsRepository;

    public List<Shop> findShopsWithin(double centerLatitude, double centerLongitude, double radiusInKm) {
        List<ShopEntity> shopEntities = shopsRepository.findByLocationWithin(new Circle(centerLongitude, centerLatitude, radiusInKm/111.12));
        List<Shop> shops = new ArrayList<>();
        for (ShopEntity shopEntity : shopEntities) {
            shops.add(new Shop(shopEntity.getPicture(), shopEntity.getName(), shopEntity.getEmail(), shopEntity.getCity(),
                    new Location(shopEntity.getLocation().getY(), shopEntity.getLocation().getX())));
        }

        return shops;
    }
}
```

I'm injecting an instance of this facade into a database adapter in the domain layer through @ComponentScan and @Autowired annotations, which i want in turn to expose as a bean to be able to inject it, as shown below:

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.hidden_founders.jobs.software_engineer_java.coding_challenge.shopfinder.tech_services.persistence")
@Component
class MongoShopsProviderAdapter implements IShopsProviderAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private MongoFacade mongoFacade;

    @Override
    public List<Shop> findShopsWithin(GeographicalCircleArea geographicalCircleArea) {
        return mongoFacade.findShopsWithin(geographicalCircleArea.getCenter().getLatitude(),
                geographicalCircleArea.getCenter().getLongitude(),
                geographicalCircleArea.getRadius());
    }
}
```

Then i try to inject an instance of this adapter into a domain class as below:

```
public class GeographicalCircleArea {
    private Location center;
    private double radius;

    @Autowired
    private IShopsProviderAdapter shopsProviderAdapter;

    GeographicalCircleArea(double centerLatitude, double centerLongitude, double radiusInKm) {
        this.center = makeCenter(centerLatitude, centerLongitude);
        this.radius = radiusInKm;
    }

    List<Shop> getShopsWithin() {
        return shopsProviderAdapter.findShopsWithin(this);
    }

    public Location getCenter() {
        return center;
    }

    public double getRadius() {
        return radius;
    }

    private Location makeCenter(double latitude, double longitude) {
        return new Location(latitude, longitude);
    }
}
```

When i use @ComponentScan along with @Component in the adapter implementation I get an error stating that spring cannot autowire the mongo Facade even if i already annotated with @Service. Please point out what I am missing and how spring boot autowiring works.

Comment: `@CompontScan` and `@Enable*` annotations are for use on `@Configuration` classes.

Comment: So how to properly inject my dependencies

Comment: You are using Spring Boot assuming your application class is in top level package it should just work.

Comment: In fact, I didn't have the application class in the top level package. Thank you a lot for your clarification!